# dc.js Percentage Histogram - Size of groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have 3 groups using `group().reduceCount()` that produce frequency counts

[image]
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to turn the counts into percents by dividing each count by the total size of the group

This would give me the size of the group

```
var valueGroupCounter = value.groupAll().value();
```

This would divide each count by the total

```
.valueAccessor(function(d) {  return (d.value/valueGroupCounter()); })
```

When I filter a section where the groups are the same or about the same size, I get the graph in the right, which is that I want, but then I filter a section where the groups have very different sizes I get the graph in the left. I want to have the 3 histogram to be about the same size by having them in percents instead of counts.
The problem is that it is giving the me the same size for the 3 groups, some groups have empty values, the 3 groups have different sizes.

I made a [pen](https://codepen.io/juanv911/pen/QWWRLeM) a added some data:

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired results by using the [Number Display Example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/number.html)
Now, the histograms are in the same range

This gives me the total size the group excluding empty values

```
valueGroupCounter.value().n
```

Divide each count by the total

```
.valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value/valueGroupCounter.value().n })
```

Forked [pen](https://codepen.io/juanv911/pen/MWYWgmN?editors=0010) corrected

[image]